# Anywhere vs somewhere

Tags: differences

Which one should I use:

> 1. Are you going somewhere nice on holiday this year?

or

> 2. Are you going anywhere nice on holiday this year?

The presence of the word "nice" bothers me a bit and deters me from using "anywhere".

Comment: You don't have to say *nice*! You could say *interesting*, or 100 other things.

Comment: @WS2 I think the OP's problem will very much persist then. They feel like *somewhere [adj]* is a kind of a fixed phrase. Which it is.

Comment: @RegDwigнt But there are plenty of adjectives they could use *outstanding, spellbinding, fascinating, appealing, attractive, exciting, riveting, relaxing, romantic etc*. There is a whole world out there, we have a glorious language at our disposal - and the only thing some people can think of is *nice*.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases these 2 sentences are equivalent, and for a lot of native english speakers, they'll be unable to discern any difference in meaning

Answer (score 7):

That's an interesting question.

In a negative polarity context (i.e. a question or negative sentence), *any* and its compounds (*anywhere*, *anything*, *anybody*) are normally used instead of *some* etc. But *some* and its compounds are also possible, with a special meaning.

I think that meaning is specificity.

> Did you bring anything?

is a neutral question, but

> Did you bring something?

implies that whatever you might have brought is something specific - not necessarily something known to the questioner, but with extra meaning to one or other of the parties.

So

> Are you going anywhere nice .. ?

is neutral, but

> Are you going somewhere nice .. ?

is suggesting that you (the person being asked) has a special place in mind (not necessarily one that the questioner knows anything about).

The difference is very subtle, though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having a hard time getting into your mindset on this one, Colin. For me in both cases it's hard to find a molecule of difference between the two words. So we may be reaching the upward bound of subtlety here.

Comment: I don't know Colin, but I agree 100% with his response. I was going to say that 'somewhere' implies a set destination, either known to one party or the other or both. It's an odd glimpse into the psychology of language and the mind.

One additional thought on this question is the emphasis of the question, which depends also on context. For example:

Are you going _any_ where nice...?

...seems to indicate that the conversation has taken a turn about the destination, in which it is determined that in general it is _not_ a special trip. :)

Comment: There's a famous paper by Robin Lakoff on this, called ["Some Reasons Why There Can't Be Any _Some/Any_ Rule"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/411442?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: I can sort of get a mental grasp on the difference - I'd ask "Somewhere" in the case I knew a person was actually going on holiday  - i.e. if they opened with "I've just booked my flights", and "anywhere" in response to "I've just booked the week off work", but again this is a subjective view!

Answer (score 4):

***Are you going somewhere nice on holiday this year?***  Using *some* makes the destination sound 'definite' and 'intended'.

***Are you going anywhere nice on holiday this year?***  Using *any* makes the destination sound 'completely unknown', 'remote' and (at least a little) 'random'.

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference is a bit subtle and probably for the most part inconsequential, but the use of one or the other is probably more common in certain situations.

> Are you going anywhere nice on holiday this year?

This might be asked when the person does not necessarily have anywhere they're going and the other person is asking in general. It's unspecific. A person might reply affirmative or negative in equal measure. A reply of a simple "No" would come off as "No, I'm not going anywhere"

> Are you going somewhere nice on holiday this year?

If someone is asked this, it implies they *are* going somewhere and the person is asking if it's a nice place. A response to this will most likely be affirmative. A reply of a simple "No" would come off more as "No, I'm not going somewhere *nice*, I'm going somewhere bad"

Comment: The discussions have been quite exhaustive and educative, and I gather both sentences are grammatically correct, with a subtle difference in meaning. Since I'm not a native speaker and have never lived in an English- speaking country, I can't get "inside" the language. In my particular case, I'd rather use "anywhere".